# Disabling unwanted menus in OpenERP

Tags: odoo

I am new to OpenERP. I need to disable some menus without uninstalling the modules that added the menus. I tried did a search for the module I wanted to disable its menu and then deleted all the search results only to get a very disorganized menu as a result. Please how do I achieve this? I just need to hide the link to two modules on the menu bar and on the home page

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you delete a parent menu, then all its children appear at the top level. You can either delete all the children as well, or just remove security access from the parent menus for all but the administrator group. You might also be able to inactivate the parent menu instead of deleting it if you don't want to mess around with security.

Answer (score 3):

Create a new security group called 'Nobody' with no users in it.

Change the permission of the menus you want to hide to this group.

This is easy and you can get the menu back easily too if you change your mind.

Answer (score 1):

check the below link.In this link is example of hide the UOM into the Product.
if We don’t want to display Unit Of Measure in Product Configuration.
http://pilgrimonerp.wordpress.com/2010/08/25/openerp-hide-menu-item/

Answer (score 1):

Easiest way is to edit the group:

`Settings > Users > Groups`, select a group, select second tab (`Security`), `add/remove` menu items on Access Menu.

Comment: No. You should duplicate the group instead of editing it directly. That way, if you end up messing something up, you can start from scratch with a default group still intact.

Answer (score 1):

To disable menus it right to go with ir.menu model.

Setting -> technical -> views -> menu

or

some easy example

http://snippetbucket.com/2014/02/openerp-disable-apps-menu-remove-openerp-app/